# What do you call a chart that looks like a half pie chart with a needle indicating a percentage?

Tags: data-visualization, interactive-visualization, pie-chart

Is there a name for this data visualization?

[image]

---

It's almost like half a pie chart. In this case, it was animated like a speedometer you would see on a car dashboard; the divider (the needle) pointed left fully horizontal at first.

Comment: I'd love to hear what Tufte would say about this! Data:ink ratio is rather poor.

Comment: I can't get enough of pop-charts .. more pls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://chandoo.org/wp/2008/09/09/excel-speedometer-chart-download/) they call it a gauge charge.

[Here](http://www.fusioncharts.com/widgets/Gallery.asp) they call it an angular gauge, speedometer or dial chart.