# What is this graph called? (Similar to a pie chart, but with dots)

Tags: data-visualization, pie-chart

The BBC has an article called [Gosport hospital deaths: The numbers behind the scandal](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-44574899) with this type of graph:

[image: Dot diagram]

What is this type of chart called?

Comment: Semi-circle, Semi-donught, semi-sunburst: http://www.tableaulearners.com/semi-sunburst-chart-tableau/

Comment: Also called parliament diagram [here](https://github.com/slashme/parliamentdiagram) and [here](https://github.com/geoffreybr/d3-parliament)

Comment: [The gauge charge, angular gauge, speedometer or dial chart](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/14558/1352) is closely related.

Answer (score 3):

> Semi-circle, Semi-doughnut, semi-sunburst: https://tableaumagic.com/sunburst-chart-tutorial/ 
> [spelling and link fixed]
> – hellpanderrr
>
> Also called parliament diagram [here](https://github.com/slashme/parliamentdiagram) and [here](https://github.com/geoffreybr/d3-parliament)  
> – AshOfFire
>
> The [gauge charge, angular gauge, speedometer or dial chart](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14558/what-do-you-call-a-chart-that-looks-like-a-half-pie-chart-with-a-needle-indicati) is closely
> related.
>   – Stephan Kolassa

Comment: I've copied these comments as a community wiki answer because they are, more or less, answers to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.

Comment: So, if the answer is simple enough that a comment can do the job, what's the big deal? Also, part of the reason why people use comments is that one-line answers often get dozens of downvotes

Comment: @David This has been discussed for a while on Meta: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/832/comments-that-are-actually-answers. Also relevant:  https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1538/why-is-our-answer-rate-so-low , https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2242/are-we-seeing-a-dramatic-drop-in-answers-per-question,  https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5325/we-have-a-very-large-widening-gap-between-questions-and-answers-how-do-we-fix & https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2083/unanswered-questions-as-percentage-of-total-why-does-cv-stand-out

Comment: The fact that four people have talked about it on Meta does not mean that the average user cares. Also, I am pretty sure that if those correct ansewrs were indeed posted an aswers, they would be downvoted

Comment: @David Also, I have rarely found that answers are penalised just because of brevity. There is a consensus in *favour* of short answers, at least when no other answers are available: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5402/121522

Comment: @David If a question is answered in the comments, that question clogs up a pipeline of unanswered questions. People seeking to address genuinely unanswered questions (as I was, when I opened this question) would waste less of their time. Also, answers that are incorrect could be downvoted (which cannot be done for comments), thereby sending a clearer signal of how useful it is to a new user enocountering it.